# Always use specific toolchain (profile agnostic) to build the app

Tags: conan, toolchain, build-system, conan-2

I want my `conan build .` to always use a certain toolchain, say clang++14 and cmake 3.20 to build itself and its dependencies. How can I accomplish that?

The reason is that our company uses either Ubuntu or Mac machines which default to different conan profiles and we want to streamline this process, also for upgrading C++ standards company wide.

**EDIT**: Either clang or gcc are installed by default on mac / ubuntu respectively, so the setup would have to make sure to install clang with its build dependencies. Can this also be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can always provide custom [profiles](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/config_files/profiles.html), not only specific settings, but also with [config](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/config_files/global_conf.html).

For instance I could have a profile for Apple Clang, that uses CMake + Ninja always:

```
[settings]
arch=armv8
build_type=Release
compiler=apple-clang
compiler.cppstd=17
compiler.libcxx=libc++
compiler.version=14
os=Macos
[tool_requires]
*:cmake/3.20@
[conf]
*:tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:generator=Ninja
```

Now you could store your profiles in a git repository, and use [conan config install](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/commands/config.html) command to install those profiles in your Conan home folder. With this mechanism, you can distribute your profiles in your company, plus, your co-workers can collaborate too.

Comment: Thx sounds like a plan! How can I make sure that clang is installed? It was not by default on my ubuntu, so can I install via conan on the fly?

Comment: Conan will not install clang for you. You need to be sure that is installed already, or, you can package clang as a Conan package and add it as a tool package in your profile. In case opting by system clang, you need to make sure that is your default compiler, otherwise, you should set is as a conf entry in your profile too: `tools.build:compiler_executables: {"c": "/<full_path>/clang", "cpp": "/<full_path>/clang++"}`. Conan will not enforce the settings.compiler to your cmake, that's why you need to set `compiler_executables`.

Comment: Another option in case you want to use system clang, but not installing manually, you could create a Conan [hook](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/extensions/hooks.html) that detects your profile and checks if the compiler is installed, then, install it in case needed. Or, if you don't want to run automatically for any command, you can create an [custom command](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/extensions/custom_commands.html) and run only once.

Comment: That's another question I had about conan: If it's not enforced, what exactly is the implications of setting the compiler in settings? Unfortunately clang is not available as of now as a conan2 recipe, however gcc is.

Comment: It implicates in the package ID, the unique identifier that marks a Conan package. 
Conan 2.x prefers things more explicit than implicit. In Conan 1.x there was many misconfiguration problems due people expecting a magic behavior. About clang package, there is an ongoing effort with llvm in Conan: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/pull/17509

Comment: So basically I can compile my app with gcc and assign it an ID that means "compiled with clang"? That's a bit confusing...

Comment: Yes, that's it.