# Conan 1.X and CMake disagree on toolchain

Tags: c++, dependency-management, conan, toolchain

I have a C++ project that has some 3rd party dependencies that I build on the fly using

```
cd build
conan install .. --build=missing
cmake ..
```

However the last command produces this error:

```
CMake Error at conan_output/conanbuildinfo.cmake:692 (message):
  Incorrect 'clang', is not the one detected by CMake: 'GNU'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  conan_output/conanbuildinfo.cmake:249 (conan_check_compiler)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (conan_basic_setup)
```

It seems conanbuildinfo checks if the compiler is actually clang but cmake wants to configure using GNU(?).

I've already discussed a similar issue in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77267019/always-use-specific-toolchain-profile-agnostic-to-build-the-app) whereas the outcome was to just nudge cmake to use the toolchain specified by the CC and CXX environmental variables in my default conan profile. However, now not even that works! Here's my default conan profile:

conan profile show default

```
Configuration for profile default:

[settings]
os=Linux
os_build=Linux
arch=x86_64
arch_build=x86_64
compiler=clang
compiler.version=14
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
build_type=Release
[options]
[conf]
[build_requires]
[env]
CC=/usr/bin/clang
CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
```

It seems to have no effect on cmake though! How can I issue cmake to use the same compiler as conan used to build the dependencies?

Comment: You forgot passing the cmake toolchain file to cmake command: -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<folder_with_toolchain>/conan_toolchain.cmake

Comment: @uilianries Ah sorry I forgot to mention, this is actually for Conan 1.6. So I guess they used to do it differently. I had to setup my conan installation within the CMake. In that case, do I still need to pass along the toolchain?

Comment: if you are using `CMakeToolchain` generator, then yes. There is the legacy `cmake` generator, but is not recommended at all, prefers `CMakeToolchain` always.

Comment: Please, read carefully how to use CMakeToolchain on Conan 1.x: https://docs.conan.io/1/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake/cmaketoolchain.html#using-the-toolchain-in-developer-flow

Comment: @uilianries alright I did read that very carefully. It seems that I can specify the compiler via cache variables in presets. However, I still think the environment variables stuff from the OP should work, no? Otherwise I would hardcode my compiler to be used by every other person in the company(that maybe doesn't have it)

Comment: You are using the legacy ``cmake`` generator, no longer recommended. The new ones like ``CMakeToolchain`` are recommended, but dropping ``cmake`` and ``conanbuildinfo.cmake`` is necessary. Likewise the ``[env]`` way to specify the environment is legacy and should be replaced with ``[buildenv]``.

Comment: Plus, in case using `CMakeTolchain`, you could use your config file to declare your compilers path, instead of environment variables, much safer and flexible: https://docs.conan.io/1/reference/config_files/global_conf.html?highlight=compiler_executables

Use the compiler_executable definition, like: `tools.build:compiler_executables: {"c": "/usr/bin/clang", "cpp": "/usr/bin/clang++"}`

Comment: @uilianries Thx that's actually what I did and it finally seems to work :) I would love to understand why the environmental variable solution doesn't work as well, so if you could provide an answer to OP with this I'd be happy to accept!

Comment: env is outdated and not compatible with cmaketoolchain. Instead, you should use buildenv: https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/config_files/profiles.html#buildenv

Comment: @uilianries Now that clears things up for me. I never understood how env worked with our old setup but in my new setup it doesn't. Didn't expect it to hinge on the CMakeToolchain.